# When does Kafka throw BufferExhaustedException?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.BufferExhaustedException: Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time 5 ms.
```

This says that exception is thrown when producer is unable to allocate memory to the record within the configured max blocking time 5 ms.

This is what it says when I was trying to add Kafka s3-sink connectors. There are 11 topics in two kafka brokers and there were consumers present already consuming from these topics. I was spinning out a 2 node Kafka connect cluster with 11 connectors trying to consume from these topics. But there was a huge spike in errors when I started these s3-sink connectors. Once I stopped these connectors, the errors dropped and seemed to be fine. Then I started the consumers again with less number of tasks and this time the errors spiked up when there was a sudden surge in the traffic and back to normal when the traffic was back to normal. There was a max retry of 5 and it messages failed to write even after 5 attempts.

From whatever I had read, it might be due to producer batch size or producer rate being higher than the consumer rate. And I guess each consumer will be occupying upto 64 mb when there is bursty traffic. Could that be the reason? Should I try and increase the blocking time?

```
Producer Config:
  lingerTime: 0
  maxBlockTime: 5
  bufferMemory: 1024000
  batchSize: 102400
  ack: "1"
  maxRequestSize: 102400
  retries: 1
  maxInFlightRequestsPerConn: 1000
```

Comment: Sink connector producer clients would really only be sending offset/config/status information back to the Connect topics, and therefore wouldn't be specific to any S3 tasks

Comment: I think this might have happened due to Kafka brokers not able to handle the number of requests and due to that, it might have blocked the producer writes, and hence the records would have started aggregating in the buffer pool, leading to exhaustion in the buffer memory. Could that be the cause? Ideally, in no way a consumer group should have an impact on the producer and this decoupling is what Kafka is all about..  Between, a great fan of yours @OneCricketeer

Comment: I don't really have experience with such a small Kafka cluster to really answer that. I'm also not sure if you can really modify the internal Connect framework Kafka producer from the connectors themselves

Comment: Producer / Source connectors aren't running in the connect cluster. Only the s3-sink connectors are running. Producers have been running as a seperate processes in other machines. Deploying these s3 sink connectors had an effect on the producer writes.

Comment: Connect _does_ run producers (as do all consumers), though, is what I'm saying. It needs them to track progress (writing back to the __consumer_offsets). If you have external producers on other machines, I fail to see how starting a decoupled consumer process would cause them to start throwing exceptions

Comment: In any case, `5ms` is far less than the default `max.block.ms` of 1 minute - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_max.block.ms

Comment: Yes, I agree 5ms is really less. Also does max.tasks have an impact if we set it to max value of the number of partitions in all the connectors? Also how much should we set in the buffer.memory for the producer? Have edited the question adding the producer config..

Comment: Again, Connect configuration would have no effect on external producer processes. The fact that producer rate might be more than consumer rate doesn't matter, and just means the consumers would have continually increasing lag. And yes, having equal or more tasks than partitions across all topics is the ideal config

Comment: We started the 9 connectors with max.tasks having equal to the number of partitions and the brokers were only 8 core machines, the CPU's I/O wait went upto 85%. Any ways to reduce this I/O wait in the Kafka brokers due to the S3 sink connectors?

Comment: You could try to make the consumers poll less frequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually due to the increase in the IOPS of the EC2 instances that Kafka brokers couldn't handle. Increasing the number of bytes fetched per poll and decreasing the frequency of polls fixed it.